# Set width/height of view programmatically

Tags: java, android, canvas, view, fragment

I have a fragment and in its onCreate method, I add a `FrameLayout`. To this FrameLayout I add an object of a class which extends from View.

Now I want to set the width and height of this view object to `wrap_content`.

This is my code and what I've tried:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmentTest, container, false);

    FrameLayout frameLayout = (FrameLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.drawingImg);

    DrawingImg drawingImgView = new DrawingImg();
    drawingImgView.getLayoutParams().height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
    drawingImgView.getLayoutParams().width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;

    // adding the view to the framelayout with the drawn picture
    frameLayout.addView(drawingImgView);

    return view;
}
```

**fragmentTest.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawingImg"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

</FrameLayout>
```

The DrawingImg class extends from View and draws an image with canvas

```
public class DrawingImg extends View {

....

}
```

My aim is that the frame layout occupies only the width and height it needs

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
drawingImgView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
drawingImgView.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
           FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

Instead of:

```
drawingImgView.getLayoutParams().height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
drawingImgView.getLayoutParams().width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
```